# How to get Quantity Order for product to display on Product Page

Tags: product, orders, magento-1, reports

Trying to get this to work, it is not return anything :(

```
 $product = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
 ->addOrderedQty()
 ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $_product->getSku());
 echo 'Already Bought '.(int)$product->ordered_qty; ?>
```

Comment: What type of product is being displayed on that page? Cause that query will not work for grouped / configurable or bundled products. So if it's not a simple that is being displayed, you need to fetch the underlying simple SKU within your composite product to get the 'already bought' info.

Comment: Tim: Yes it is on a configurable page... sorry (facepalm)

Comment: @brentwpeterson did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As part of the function `addOrderedQty` it will only add product information for the simple product types. What you could to is rewrite this function so that it does not add the following to the join conditions.

```
$adapter->quoteInto('(e.type_id NOT IN (?))', $compositeTypeIds),
```

Then this will give you the information about all product types. Once you have this information you can simply get the first item and get the ordered_qty.

```
$product->getFirstItem()->getOrderedQty();
```

Answer (score 2):

The result of `Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')` is report collection and not report object. To get information you want try this

```
$productReportsCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addOrderedQty()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $_product->getSku());
$productReport = $productReportsCollection->getFirstItem();

echo 'Already Bought ' . (int)$productReport->ordered_qty;
```

Comment: it's working fine but i want to get these all product total amount so have you any idea about this?